# Can the items in health app be edited?

Tags: ios, iphone, health.app

I swim with (some) regularity. Is there a way for me to edit the Health app fitness section to add a Swim chart / category?

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/speedo-fit-swim-fitness/id385166726?mt=8

Comment: How the health app works is NOT very well documented by Apple, I went on a hunt one day for another question on this site.  For a swim chart (if it even exists) to become active however you most likely need a data collection [accessory](http://store.apple.com/us/accessories/all-accessories/fitness) and its own app, that feeds data to the health app.

Comment: @Buscar웃 - Does that app sync with Apple's Health app?

Comment: They say - Speedo Fit swim app to track your swim workouts is available from US, Canada, UK, France and Mexico app stores here. Version 3.1 with HealthKit integration will be live in the app store later today (16th October).

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it - it only adds "active calories", which is meaningless to me. It doesn't add a new type of workouts.